# Puppet agent can't be deployed module from master

Tags: puppet

I'm just start learning Puppet, really new to this world. I'm using puppet 2.7.26 on my two learning VMs --
puppet-master 192.168.160.131
eisen-suse11 192.168.160.129
Follow the turial, I've signed the node "eisen-suse11" to puppet-master successfully--

```
puppet-master:/etc/puppet/modules/motd/manifests # puppet cert --list --all
+ "eisen-suse11"         (A0:7F:E2:77:30:9A:96:E3:79:FD:F7:1E:59:35:5B:1E)
+ "puppet-master"        (38:90:B5:8A:68:8A:A7:44:8A:2F:07:D3:F3:AC:E8:80) (alt names: "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet-master", "DNS:puppet-master.suse11", "DNS:puppet.suse11")
+ "puppet-master.suse11" (5D:9E:A4:D9:0C:5F:69:07:FA:55:13:C3:38:6D:9B:26)
```

Then follow the book, I write a module -- motd -- which should put a file to client node --

```
puppet-master:/etc/puppet/modules/motd/manifests # cat init.pp
class motd{
      package{ 'setup':
      ensure => present,
  }
  file{ '/etc/motd':
        ensure  => present,
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0644',
        source  => "puppet://$puppetserver/modules/motd/etc/motd",
        require => Package['setup']
    }
}
puppet-master:/etc/puppet/modules/motd/manifests # cat site.pp
$puppetserver='puppet-master.suse11'
node 'eisen-suse11'{
    include motd
}
```

But when I tested "puppet agent --test --trace" on the client node -- eisen-suse11 --- it's all quiet --

```
eisen-suse11:~ # puppet agent --test --trace
info: Caching catalog for eisen-suse11
info: Applying configuration version '1633779962'
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds

    eisen-suse11:~ # ls /etc/motd
    ls: cannot access /etc/motd: No such file or directory

   That "/etc/motd" is not copied from puppet-master -- 
   Does anyone can help? Any idea would be appreciated.
```

RGS
Eisen

Comment: Puppet 2.7 is far past end-of-life and wholly obsolete.  Do not use it for anything.  It is not useful even for learning Puppet.  As I write this, the current release is 7.11.0, and a great deal has changed since Puppet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your node is receiving an empty catalog, which is happening because you put your `site.pp` file in the wrong place.  Puppet will not find it inside the module. It has been a very long time since I wrote code for Puppet 2 (and I hung on to that version much longer than was healthy), but as I recall, the correct directory for that file would be `/etc/puppet/manifests`.

But again, as I wrote in comments, Puppet 2 is utterly obsolete and well past the end of its life.  Ditch it, and also ditch any books you have that teach it.  The only reason I can think of to learn this version of Puppet is that you have an existing legacy infrastructure that you are obligated to maintain, but if you are faced with such a Puppet code base in 2021 then it would be best to rewrite from scratch for Puppet 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Follow your answer. Finally the puppet works. And I'm using puppet 2.7 only because my suse11's default puppet is ver2.7... I'm going to upgrade it to 7 later. 
Thanks again for your kindness and guide

Comment: Upgrade now, @EisenWang.  Do not devote any effort to learning Puppet 2.  As a new user, you will be far better off going straight to the latest version.  Open source Puppet is available free of charge.